# Datatables responsive is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here [Sample Link](https://indiaruler.com/trains-between-stations), I am using responsive datatables but If you check in mobile version it does not seem to work properly. This is the code I have used to make it responsive:

```
$('#listTbl').dataTable({
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    responsive: true
});
```

I dont know why its not working as expected. Its working [here](https://indiaruler.com/seat-availability/ahmedabad-jn-to-mumbai-central/ADI-BCT) very well. Any idea what could be wrong there?

Comment: A solution with css helps?

Comment: Open your browser console. There might be some errors.

Comment: It works for me, see http://imgur.com/a/Fv4Pp